# Emojis in XAML & C# on WP8.1 with longer Unicode range

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, emoji

I am seeing a very weird behavior in my WP8.1 APP. In my XAML I have the following, which perfectly translates into a nice 😠 (ANGRY FACE), all is right.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="FaceTextBlock" Text="&#x1F620;" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" />
```

But when I try to do it programmatically, it behaves as if the last digit - '0' - was not there:

```
FaceTextBlock.Text = "\u1F620"; // This behaves like "\u1F62" and is displayed  as "ὢ0"
```

As a counter example, I tried using the simple "Plane Emoji" ✈ "U+2708" which works fine. Any idea what I am missing here? Could it be due to the culture?

```
FaceTextBlock.Text = "\u2708"; // This works fine
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Unicode character escape in C# is represented using either 4 or 8 hex digits so you have to write the emoji using 8 digits:

```
"\U0001F620"
```

Note the capital U as documented in [2.4.1 Unicode character escape sequences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664669(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: You are absolutely right. I would have never thought about that! Thanks a lot Martin.